# Bootstrap site not being responsive on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Update**: I've changed over the `%` and made `px` values `max-width` but it's still not being responsive with images, nor is the mobile menu working.. ([link to website](http://www.brilliantcareersatmazars.co.za/emailers/mazarsmessenger/html/august15/article.html))

I am working on a site using Bootstrap, and for some reason it is not being responsive. I have the `viewport` set to  `meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"`

`Bootstrap.css` first, then the `theme.css`.

Comment: to make site responsive add the .col-md-* , .col-sm-* , .col-xs-* for medium, small, extra small devices

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a responsive website you should **stop** using **fixed widths**. For example on your website, you have a class named **".contacts"** and the image "Mazars Messenger"(**add a class here and use it instead of img from my code)**. Try to set these properties to it and see what happens:

```css
.contacts{
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*here you add your own class instead of img to affect only the image with that class*/
img{
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    max-width: 970px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And you have the borders as images under every article. You need to modify the code for those too, and then your site should be responsive.
You need to do this for your entire website. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, i'm tried above code, but the image is still not being responsive? http://www.brilliantcareersatmazars.co.za/emailers/mazarsmessenger/html/august15/article.html

Comment: That's because this is another page and you are using inline style on the image from the page in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

1) Your `col-lg-1` and `col-lg-10` classes need to be immediately inside a div with `row` class, that is inside `container` class. Do not wrap them in `modal-body` either - this is stopping the responsive grid styles from working properly.

2) You should probably add some `col-md-**` and `col-sm-**` classes to your columns as well, to give better control of proportion at medium and small size, instead of just specifying the large size.

3) Take all fixed widths off your classes inside `container`.

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing some width values in pixels, for example here:

```
.contacts {
    width: 800px;
    display: block;
}
```

If you want it to be responsive you need to set values in percentage like so:

```
.contacts {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I've changed over the % and made px values max-width but it's still not being responsive with images, not is the mobile menu working... http://www.brilliantcareersatmazars.co.za/emailers/mazarsmessenger/html/august15/article2.html

Comment: you should do the same for the image:

.headerpic img {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: also, you should give a background-color to your mobile menu...        .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}